# Where to report issues of snaps?

Tags: snap, bug-reporting, launchpad

I don't seem to find any information where to report issues with snaps, i.e. applications which are installed through `snap install` instead of the system package manager `apt-get`.

Since most bug reports on launchpad.net are simply ignored, but still make sense to be filed, I'd like to make sure that I'm not doing something even more hopeless when filing bugs with `ubuntu-bug` or manually on launchpad.net.

The fact that apport says that a package isn't installed shouldn't say too much because it usually takes years until this tool is upgraded to reflect changes in the requirements.

Comment: It depends on the snap. Usually if you `snap info <snapname>` you get a "Contact" field which often links to a bug tracker. e.g. the Spotify snap links to their community support site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you run `$ snap info <snap-name>` you will see a contact field. This will tell you how to talk to the developer, or where can you find that information.

```
$ snap info parity
name:      ...
summary:   ...
publisher: ...
contact:   https://parity.io
[...]
```

Comment: The contact info for kdenlive lists the KDE bugzilla. But the problem with the kdenlive snap isn't with kdenlive, it's with the snap (it doesn't package melt, needed in order to actually render the videos).

Comment: Don't see this field on my snaps.

Answer (score 1):

If the Snap is misleading, violates trademark, contains malware, or for some other serious reason should be suspended from distribution by snapd, then report the offending snap to Canonical maintainers of the Snap Store. DON'T report ordinary bug this way -- contact the snap author directly for ordinary bugs.

1. Find the Snap Package page in the [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/store). Here's an example of the Hello World snap page in the Snap Store:

[image]

2. Scroll down to the bottom of the page. Click on the "Report this app" link.

[image]

3. Detail your discovery of malware, trademark violation, security problem, etc. DON'T report ordinary non-security bugs here -- contact the Snap author directly for those.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The official answer is: If is from canonical, sending a email to `snaps@canonical.com` with the bug.

For test the message try execute `ubuntu-bug <snap package here>` and see the email or link to contact for issues or execute `snap info <package> | grep contact:`.