# Where and how to report bugs with Gnome Snaps from Canonical?

Tags: gnome, snap

I tried to get advice in the Snapcraft forums but no one answered so far: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/where-or-how-do-i-report-this-bug-with-gnome-characters-and-communitheme-snap/10654

> I'm using 18.04 and the Characters snap worked fine until it was updated a few weeks ago. I'm also using the Communitheme snap which seems to be involved in triggering the bug. Window decorations and sidebar of the app are not visible except some white text/glyphs.
>
> [image: gno]
>
> Plain text:
>
> ```
> (org.gnome.Characters:17824): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:59:46.674: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:0: Failed to import: Error opening file /snap/communitheme/current/share/themes/Communitheme/gtk-3.20/gtk.css: Permission denied
> Gjs-Message: 20:59:46.676: JS LOG: Zeichen-Anwendung gestartet
>
> (org.gnome.Characters:17824): GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: 20:59:47.985: Failed to load XKB rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml: Failed to open file “/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml”: No such file or directory
> ```
>
> I'm not sure where to report this, it's said to be an officially supported snap by Canonical but it has no bug tracking on launchpad ([1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-characters), [2](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/gnome-characters/snap)) as far as i can see, not on GitHub, not contact in snap info as other packages have or on the respective snapcraft page. And I also doubt that the Gnome bugtracker is the right place when another snap is involved.
>
> Can someone please give me directions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `snap info` to find out where to place a bug report, in this case we get:

```
~$ snap info gnome-characters
name:      gnome-characters
summary:   A character map application
publisher: Canonical✓
contact:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-characters/+bugs?field.tag=snap
license:   GPL-3.0+
description: |
  Characters is a simple utility application to find and
  insert unusual characters.
snap-id: qJcS3UjpF9AMJKWAiKwA5EWbm0y6Uduw
channels:
  stable:    v3.32.1+git1.2050bba 2019-05-01 (258) 15MB -
  candidate: v3.32.1+git1.2050bba 2019-05-01 (258) 15MB -
  beta:      ↑                                          
  edge:      v3.32.0+git9.4424d0f 2019-05-08 (260) 15MB -
```

So https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-characters/+bugs?field.tag=snap is where you can file your bug report.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I was sure I checked https://askubuntu.com/q/1005843/40581 and couldn't find such info.