# Theme issue with Gnome Characters snap using the Communitheme snap

Tags: 18.04, gnome, snap

I have this problem I described here where a snap (Gname Characters) says it can't find theme resources (from a snap):
[Where and how to report bugs with Gnome Snaps from Canonical?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1142288/40581)

[image]

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about snaps and theming but just had a closer look at VLC and the Gnome Characters snap and I noticed the broken symlink `~/snap/gnome-characters/current/themes`:

[image]

This exists even when removing the respective snap folder for the app, removing and then reinstalling the snap.

Combining knowledge about the broken link with the error message (`/snap/communitheme/current/share/themes/Communitheme/gtk-3.20/gtk.css: Permission denied`
) we can fix this.

```
rm ~/snap/gnome-characters/current/.themes
cp -av /snap/communitheme/current/share/themes ~/snap/gnome-characters/current/.themes
```

[image]

Looks better now. If you use a different theme you have to use the respective path of the theme. I'm aware the this is probably not the most elegant solution, the VLC snap has more themes in this folder like Adwaita and others which should also be included? I'm not sure.

According to my other question I now opened a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-characters/+bug/1828664