# Doesn't Ubuntu patch for Spotify?

Tags: spotify

Spotify's GUI freezes constantly on Ubuntu 18.04.x and 19.10 also on side project Ubuntu Mate 19.10. 
When I start Spotify out the CLI I see errors popping up:

```
$ spotify
Gtk-Message: 09:59:33.346: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 09:59:33.347: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: 09:59:33.351: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

So I started with experimenting and this brought me to Mint Tricia Mate where I just gambled my way through and not surprisingly Spotify works flawlessly on Mint. 
During installation I saw the regular install but also a pop up for extra dependencies. I looked for these dependencies in Synaptic but they weren't there.

How can I (we) use our, paid, Spotify app in a decent way on Ubuntu?

Also to mention: the startup of the app is much faster on Mint Mate than it is on Ubuntu (also Mate that I tried) 19.10.

Can we download these dependencies somewhere or is there a way to use even Spotify on Ubuntu as the Community of Spotify has a whole lot complaints about Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10 and a freezing Spotify UI. I feel that Mint proved it is not the app but the OS that is the problem.

How can I fix this as I do not want Mint at all?

Comment: This site is not the right place to report bugs, see [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to the question I had. 
1) Do NOT install Spotify as a snap !! but install it as previous as spotify-client with the manual import of keyring and update package. See on their support site or OMG Ubuntu for the howto's (Google brings you fast there). 
2) Install synaptic if you don't have it yet. 
3) Open Synaptic and typ "spotify" in the search field . 
4) You'll see spotify-client installed , but there is another package spotify-client-gnome-support . Mark that and install it .

Done .... No freezes anymore and no big errors on startup. 
I hope many users have a good use of my long search for a solution on 19.10 Ubuntu Gnome.

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/install-spotify-ubuntu-linux

the link above is the howto for installing as a client instead of a snap (avoid that installation !!!)

I know it sounds like a bug, but I see it more that the snap-store of Ubuntu is untrustable and that isn't really a bug, is it ?

Comment: Thank you for downvotes ! This is really supportive for end users ;(

Comment: Your question reminds me of an off-topic rant - https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask  (FYI: I didn't down vote, but still didn't like the way your question was written so I can understand the downvotes)

Comment: You should still report the bug of the snap. See [Where to report issues of snaps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005843/where-to-report-issues-of-snaps) or [Where Do We Report Snap Issues|Probable Bugs?](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/where-do-we-report-snap-issues-probable-bugs/11843)

Comment: Done @ the Spotify community ...

Comment: FYI I have the same problem in Linux Mint, so it's not really Ubuntu specific.

Comment: Well to be honest, I installed it in Linux Mint and there was no problem at all ... so i came to the conclusion it is, was ?, a snap problem. Linux Mate latest version on today